# Google website optimizer and nested tests

Tags: javascript, google-website-optimizer, usability-testing

I am running a test on a landing page. The conversion is a "signup" page with a form.

I would like now to test some form designs, and find an optimized version.

Can I use my form (conversion page for first test) as a new original for my new test?
Does it go in conflict with GWO logic?

Thank you

Comment: A diagram for this scenario is here: http://bit.ly/nHxXy3

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't be a problem at all.  You can definitely run many concurrent tests on a site.  In this case you're running Test A (current test) and Test B (form optimization test).  You'll have:

### Landing Page

- Test A Control code
- Test A Sections

### Signup Page

- Test B Control code
- Test A Goal code
- Test B Sections

### Confirmation Page or Submit button click event

- Test B Goal code

The existence of Test A's goal code on the signup page won't make any difference.  GWO uses a modified version of Google Analytics, and basically every test is a separate account.  They shouldn't create any conflict with each other.

One note: I've not run separate instances of the control code on the same page, but I think that's safe, too.